# How to structure more than one function on git for automated deploy on Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, bitbucket

I'm start using the Google Cloud Functions and I've see that has an option to make an automated deploy from the bitbucket. I have multiple functions to deploy, should I have one repo per functions or can I have one repo but divided by directories or something else?

that is what I'm talking about: 
[Deploying from Source Control](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/repo)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple functions in a single repo. A common structure would be as follows:

```
.
├── common
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
├── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Where `main.py` contains both functions:

```
from common import module1, module2

def cloudfunction1(request):
    ...

def cloudfunction2(request):
    ...
```

And you deploy those functions either directly by name:

```
$ gcloud functions deploy cloudfunction1 --runtime python37 --trigger-http --source https://source.developers.google.com/...
$ gcloud functions deploy cloudfunction2 --runtime python37 --trigger-http --source https://source.developers.google.com/...
```

Or by entrypoint:

```
$ gcloud functions deploy foo --runtime python37 --entry-point cloudfunction1 --trigger-http --source https://source.developers.google.com/...
$ gcloud functions deploy bar --runtime python37 --entry-point cloudfunction2 --trigger-http --source https://source.developers.google.com/...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sadly main.py can get really big, loading many modules and affecting cold start. It would be better if we could specify a different main file for each function.